# How can I center an absolutely positioned element with arbitrary left position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a range slider that I want to have some content positioned exactly above the thumb of the slider. When the thumb is in the middle of the slider, I can have the content as so:

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

When the slider value changes, I update the `left` value of the content in JS, however, due to the transform, it is no longer right in the middle of the thumb.

I'm wondering if there is some type of formula I can use to calculate the transform value based on the left percentage to always keep it in the middle?

Here is a minimal example of what I am currently doing and how it's not working as intended. The number value is off center from the thumb everywhere except for right in the middle.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]')
const valueEl = document.querySelector(".value");

const sliderPercentage = (min, max, value) => {
    const minimum = min === "" ? 0 : parseInt(min);
    const maximum = max === "" ? 100 : parseInt(max);
    return ((value - minimum) * 100) / (maximum - minimum)
}

const handleChange = e => {
   const value = e.target.valueAsNumber;
   const percentage = sliderPercentage(e.target.min, e.target.max, value);
   valueEl.textContent = value;
   valueEl.style.left = `${percentage}%`
   // How do I update the translateX property accordingly? 
}

input.addEventListener("input", handleChange)
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.value {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

input[type="range"] {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="value">50</div>
  <input type="range" />
</div>
```

Comment: You should probably just use the thumb as the "anchor element" and position the `.content` from that element. This way, no matter where that thumb goes, the `.content` element will always follow

Comment: @konekoya how can I acheive that with the `input:-webkit-slider-thumb` element?

Comment: Thanks for putting together an example. But what's your content element? It seems like the `.value` is already positioned correctly according to the thumb?

Comment: Believe it or not, but a custom 'range slider' is still a pain to create because UA vendors (FF, Chrome, Edge, Safari, etc) are not consistent in their design. You will need to know exactly how the slider is build up, where margins are used, thumb width/height, to name a few. It's a bees nest. Better search a site like Codepen for *range slider tooltip* and use what best fits your needs. Here's a jQuery version I found: [Cross Browser, Responsive, Custom Range Slider](https://codepen.io/senerdude/pen/VBZrgL)

Comment: I did one myself a few months ago: [Codepen: custom range slider with variable scale and values](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/Expxwwo). It's not with a tooltip, but maybe useful as an alternative...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get closer to what you want in a slightly different way.

I put a percentage width on the `div` with the class of `value` and then center aligned the text within that `div`.

In this way, it is not necessary to worry about the width of the numbers changing. Otherwise, you would need to calculate the left offset differently for single digits (i.e. 0 to 9), double digits (i.e. 10 to 99), and triple digits (i.e. 100).

Apart from that, the transform was not necessary and I changed the `position` to `relative` in the `value` class.

The numbers used in `calcLeftOffset` were established by trial and error as was the percentage of 9% in the `value` class.

I set the width of the slider to 99% so that it did not go right to the end of the container.

It seems to work in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.

I put a yellow background on the `div` with the class of `value` so that you can see that the `div` is maintaining its relative position above the thumb of the slider.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]')
const valueEl = document.querySelector(".value");

const sliderPercentage = (min, max, value) => {
  const minimum = min === "" ? 0 : parseInt(min);
  const maximum = max === "" ? 100 : parseInt(max);
  return ((value - minimum) * 100) / (maximum - minimum)
}

const calcLeftOffset = percentage => {
  return percentage * 97 / 100 - 3;
}

const handleChange = e => {
  const value = e.target.valueAsNumber;
  const percentage = sliderPercentage(e.target.min, e.target.max, value);
  valueEl.textContent = value;
  valueEl.style.left = `${calcLeftOffset(percentage)}%`
}

input.addEventListener("input", handleChange)
valueEl.style.left = `${calcLeftOffset(50)}%`
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.value {
  position: relative;
  width: 9%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}

input[type="range"] {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 99%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="value">50</div>
  <input type="range" />
</div>
```